# How to understand "owner" tag in repo xml

Tags: repo

I get a repo xml but don't fully understand it.how could I understand "owner" tag in repo xml?
I try to google some answers but failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV9Yy.png)

Comment: Could you add more details and tags? I think this is not getting any attention because nobody knows what is "repo xml"

Comment: I'm tring to manager my repositories by repo. I get some xml files for study.In these xml files I find "owner" tag,but couldn't find meaning of it.  I'm very sorry to that I really can only give you so much information.I'm a green hand of repo

Comment: According to the specification, `owner` does not appear to be a standard attribute for `project`. It's likely that your question is particular to your environment.

See: https://git-repo.info/en/docs/multi-repos/manifest-format/